# How to shutdown an application added by reference?

Tags: c#, wpf

Suppose I've two application:

1. App1 (that is the main app where the App2 is added by reference)
2. App2 added by reference to App1

now the problem's that when I close the `App2` (when the `App1`) is opened I get both the app closed, infact in the `Closing` event I've this content:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

I tried to fix in this way:

```
 base.OnClosing(e);
 Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

this will keep opened the `App1` but at the same time when I start only the `App2` (not from `App1`) the app is still opened, I can see this 'cause the debug session isn't closed.

How can I manage this situation? Thanks.

**Update**

I call `App2` from `App1` executing this code:

```
App2.MainWindow.Instance.Show();
```

where `Instance` in `App2` is defined in this way:

```
public static MainWindow Instance
{
    get
    {
        if(AppWindow == null)
        {
            AppWindow = new MainWindow();
            AppWindow.InitializeComponent();
            AppWindow.Closed += (x, y) => 
            {
                AppWindow = null;
            };
        }

        return AppWindow;
    }
}
```

the variable `AppWindow` is defined in that way:

```
 public partial class MainWindow
 {
    public static MainWindow AppWindow;

    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       AppWindow = this;
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to show how are you actually calling the second app. please edit this and post more relevant code.

Comment: @MethodMan yep! Added new details :)

Comment: you are assigning `AppWindow = this` which this int this instance is MainWindow. you should not create instances of UserControls or Windows in WPF like this. I assume this is WPF.?

Comment: I need to access to the `MainWindow` instance

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @johnn - you can [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if you want.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the default for WPF applications is to shut down when their main window closes. To change that, set the [ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `OnExplicitShutdown` either in your XAML or in code before you open your main window. You will then need to call the [Shutdown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms597013(v=vs.110).aspx) method explicitly when you think it's time to exit your application.

That said, the way you reference another *app* is very weird, normally you reference another `Window`. I have no idea what happens when two apps are running at the same time. You may want to straighten that out too, the solution above is really just a quick workaround for your problem of having two apps.